# Cannot use dynamic key with inferred constant string type assertion for Redux action in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHsIs.png)I'm currently working on type-checking for badly typed library which handles redux actions. My intention is to monkey patch it's declarations with type assertions. I've done exactly that but facing some strange problem with string constants representing action type:

[unexpected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMjtd.png)

Here is typing declarations:

```
import {
    createAction as originalCreateAction,
    handleActions as originalHandleActions
} from 'redux-actions-helpers';

type DeepReadOnly<T extends object> = {
    readonly [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends object
        ? DeepReadOnly<T[key]>
        : T[key];
};

export type UnkwonObject = Record<string, unknown>;

type CreateAction = {
    <
        GObject extends UnkwonObject,
        ActionName extends string,
        ActionCreator extends (...args: any[]) => GObject
    >(
        actionName: ActionName,
        handler: ActionCreator
    ): {
        (...args: any[]): ReturnType<ActionCreator> & {
            type: ActionName;
        };
        toString(): ActionName;
    };

    <
        GObject extends UnkwonObject,
        ActionName extends string,
        ActionCreator extends (...args: any[]) => GObject
    >(
        actionName: string
    ): {
        (...args: any[]): ReturnType<ActionCreator> & {
            type: ActionName;
        };
        toString(): ActionName;
    };
};

type ActionsObject<State, ActionsMap> = {
    [Key in keyof ActionsMap]: ActionsMap[Key] extends (
        ...args: any[]
    ) => infer Result
        ? (state: State, payload: Result) => State
        : never;
};

type HandleActions = {
    <
        State extends object,
        ActionsMap extends UnkwonObject,
        IsImmutable extends boolean = true
    >(
        actionsObject: ActionsObject<
            IsImmutable extends true ? DeepReadOnly<State>: State,
            ActionsMap
        >,
        options: {
            initialState: IsImmutable extends true
                ? DeepReadOnly<State>
                : State;
            strict?: boolean;
        }
    ): any;
};

export const createAction = originalCreateAction as CreateAction;
export const handleActions = originalHandleActions as HandleActions;
```

So basically I'm using generic to infer action type as constant string. Also on action creator I have method toString() that returns same string constant action type and type checking fully enabled. But somehow I can use only string literal in object or variable in which I store result of .toString() in advance. But If I try as dynamic key

```
setPersonals.toString()
```

which returns exactly same type I lost my type-checking. What's the problem here?

I've tried googling, experimenting and reading documentation

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to use this library, instead of our official Redux Toolkit package? RTK has already been designed to work great with TypeScript and simplify the amount of TS types you have to write yourself: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I also love redux toolkit, but the problem here is that this legacy library is being used on project on my first job I've recently found. There's healthy technologies in project like typescript and React hooks but that stupid library that results in 'any' everytime I'm working with state is annoying...